# revert the spl_object_hash php , get an object from his hash php , get an object from his reference

Tags: php, reference, spl

**PHP : How to get an object from his hash ? [ how to revert the spl_object_hash ]**

***Example :***

```
$a = new A();
$adressOfA = spl_object_hash($a);

//... laters ...
// I want to get the instance stored in the $adressOfA, kind of
$theSameAButInAnotherVariable = some_function($adressOfA);
```

Thank you for your helping in advance.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of spl_object_hash($a); it isn't a pointer/reference/address to the original object, simply a unique id for the object.... if you need to use it as a pointer, then build an array of your objects using $adressOfA as the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible (hashes are irreversible, the hash itself is not the "address") and it does not even make sense to try, because:

1. as soon as the object does not exist anymore, the id that is used for the hash will be assigned to other objects. If you want to persist an object across different processes, you can use `serialize()` instead.
2. as long as the object still exists, you can pass it directly. The variable `$a` does not actually hold the object as value, but an object identifier as reference. So you don't need to worry about memory or object copies.